# Google pubsub push subsciption "not registred"

Tags: publish-subscribe

I would like to create a push subscription to an endpoint (a kubernetes ingress endpoint) 
I have follow 
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push?authuser=1&hl=fr 
and 
https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/managing-notifications?authuser=1&hl=fr&authuser=1&visit_id=636873901965728364-1969465896&rd=1 
in order to validate the domain used by this endpoint.

In Google search console I see my validated domain.

Unfortunately

```
gcloud beta pubsub subscriptions create subscription2 --topic=top3 --push-endpoint=https://mydomainValidated

ERROR: Failed to create subscription [projects/xxxxx/subscriptions/subscription2]: The supplied HTTP URL is not registered in the subscription's parent project (url="https://mydomainValidated", project_id="xxxxxxxxxx").
```

ERROR: (gcloud.beta.pubsub.subscriptions.create) Failed to create the following: [subscription2]

It's the same when I use nodejs API to create the subscription. It also does not work using GCP interface.

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 0):

Ok Found !

Il the API&Services > Domain validation part of the process I used "mydomainValidated" to validate 
In fact you should use "https://mydomainValidated"

Hope it will helps